# unable to find a React.Component by id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `React.Component` with `render()` declared this way:

```
render(){
    return <div>
        <button id="butt" onClick={()=> $("#noti").change("test") }>click me</button>
        <Notification id="noti" onMounted={() => console.log("test")}/>
    </div>
}
```

And this is my `Notification` class:

```
class Notification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            message: "place holder",
            visible: false
        }
    }

    show(message, duration){
        console.log("show")
        this.setState({visible: true, message})
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({visible: false})
        }, duration)
    }

    change(message){
        this.setState({message})
    }

    render() {
      const {visible, message} = this.state
      return <div>
          {visible ? message : ""}
      </div>
    }
  }
```

As the class name suggests, I am trying to create a simple notification with message. And I want to simply display the notification by calling `noti.show(message, duration)`.

However, when I try to find `noti` by doing `window.noti`, `$("#noti")` and `document.findElementById("noti")`, they all give me `undefined`, while `noti` is displayed properly. And I can find the `butt` using the code to find `noti`.

How should I find the `noti`? I am new to front end so please be a little bit more specific on explaining.

Comment: Can you check your console and paste any errors that you are getting here?

Comment: @johnmikelridzz I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I think you should explain what do you want to do with that `Notification` component? If you are new to Frontend and considering using React, you should think in React way. Let us know your desire, so we can give you  better suggestions. Do not try to pick your component like this. But if you really want to do this then @Alireza Esfahani answer is really useful for you.

Comment: @devserkan As the class name suggests, I am trying to create a simple notification.  And I can simply show that notification by calling `notifcation.show(message, duration)`.

Comment: I mean, what is your intention for "selecting" that component? Again, you should think in React way. You should use state, props and other goodies React provides you. Do not try to "select" a component like this. Do you want to show that component at some point in your app? Then use state and let your component get that state change and rendered.

Comment: @devserkan I am not sure about what you mean. I just want to show a notification that shows for a while then disappears and I want the notification can be used anywhere. And doing that way is the only thing that I know as I am a newbie.

Comment: Ok, but you can do it in many ways. Also, what kind of notification is this? Just a modal for example? Do not depend on classes so much (personal opinion). Just go through [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) if you haven't seen it yet. Get comfortable with the state, props, and other stuff. For example, I could write that notification component just as a functional one and pass the relevant props to it, then render it anywhere, anytime when I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea using JQuery library  with Reactjs. instead you can find a appropriate react library for notification or anything else.

Also In React we use `ref` to to access DOM nodes.
Something like this:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.noti = React.createRef();
    }

    ...

    <Notification ref={this.noti} onMounted={() => console.log("test")}/>
```

more info:  [https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html](http://%20https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have hardcoded the id to 'noti' in the render method. You can also use the prop id in the Notification component.I have remodelled the component so that you can achieve the intended functionality through React way.

```
    class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          messageContent: 'placeholder'
        }
      }

      setMessage = (data) => {
        this.setState({messageContent : data});
      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div className="App">
            <button id='butt' onClick= {() => this.setMessage('test')} />
            <Notification message = {this.state.messageContent} />
          </div>
        );
      }

    }

    class Notification extends React.Component {

      render () {
        const {message} = this.props;
        return (
          <div id='noti'>
            {message}
          </div>
        )
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before beginning:** Using id/class to reach DOM nodes is not suggested in React.js, you need to use Ref's. Read more at [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

---

In your first render method, you give *id property* to Notification component.
In react.js,

> if you pass a property to some component, it becomes a props of that
>   component. [(read more here)](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

After you give the id to Notification, you need to take and use that specific props in your Notification component.

You see that you inserted a code line `super(props)` in constructor of Notification? That means, take all the props from super (upper) class and inherit them in this class.

Since id is HTML tag, you can use it like:

```js
class Notification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // inherit all props from upper class
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: "place holder",
            visible: false,
            // you can reach all props with using this.props
            // we took id props and assign it to some property in component state
            id: this.props.id
        }
    }

    show(message, duration){
       // code..
    }

    change(message){
       // code..
    }

    render() {
      const {visible, message, id} = this.state
      // give that id to div tag
      return <div id={id}>
          {message}
      </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: How will he reach the Notification component by id?

Comment: By simply using smth. like this: *document.findElementById(id)*. He didn't mention to reach it as component, as html.

Comment: @alpay `document.findElementById(id)` gives me `undefined` as explained in the question. And I am not sure about what you mean by "as component, as html".

Comment: @alpay In react you cannot reach components with document.getElementById, there is ref in react for this purpose, you should read refs

Comment: @Seaky You should avoid using jQuery with react.js. Ref's are designed specifically to reach DOM. But if you give id to specific element, you can reach it as dom object (<div id="noti">Message</div>) by using document.findElementById. 

If you want to reach it as React component, you should use Refs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass id/class to a React Component as you would declare them in your normal HTML. any property when passed to a React Component becomes a props of that component which you have to use in the component class/function.

```
render() {
      const {visible, message} = this.state
      // give your id props to div tag as id attr
      return <div id={this.props.id}>
          {message}
      </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not provide the exact answer about selecting a component as you want. I'm providing this answer so you can see other alternatives (more React way maybe) and improve it according to your needs.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isNotiVisible: false
  };

  handleClick = () => this.setState({ isNotiVisible: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Show Noti</button>
        {this.state.isNotiVisible && (
          <Noti duration={2000} message="This is a simple notification." />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Noti extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ visible: false }), this.props.duration);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.visible && <div>{this.props.message}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to encapsulate the notification? Like calling `noti.show(message, duration)`. I want it to be used as simple as `alert()` and the message should not be a fixed one.

Comment: If I understood you right what you want by saying encapsulation is already done in my example. I decide when I show that notification and I give it the needed props. Isn't that what you want? When you write something as a component in React then you should use it like one. Give it some props! The `message` and  `duration` is not fixed as you can see. Do not use your component like `component(something)` do it like `<Component aProp={something} />`

Comment: So if I want to show a notification of "typo" then show a notification of "success". How is that achieved in your code? It looks like I need two `Noti`s?

Comment: If you want to show two notifications, yeah you render two `Noti`s. Since the context is different ("typo", "success", etc) you can render as many components as you want. In your way, don't you need to call two `noti`s, too? Actually, this is related to how you want to build and use your component. This is a very, very simple (and has some faults maybe) example. I just wanted to show how you should think about it in the React way. By the way, you can make the messages dynamic and bind them some props like "typo", "success" etc then render your component according to predefined messages.

Comment: Message should not be predefined because I am not the only one who writes this project. Using more `noti`s needs more logic to control the visibility of the notifications while function calling is very simple because I only need to change the parameters I pass in.

Comment: Then use props? So, you just need to change the message prop. In my example, you can pass the `message` as you can see. I said "predefined" because you said different types such as "typo" and "success". I thought you just want to pass props like that. I really didn't get what is the difference between `noti.show(message, duration)` and `<Noti message="foo" duration={3000} />` and you think that the second one need more logic :)